# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" (and no source code available)

Tags: java, jar

I'm really stuck here...

A project I'm working on requires a Java .jar for some interfacing to an API. Thing is, I only have the executable .jar file and not much else, but when I try to run it I get an error saying that

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

So I google that and the general consensus seems to be that I need the slf4j library. Which I have downloaded and after some work with classpaths and stuff, it finally seem to recognize the library, but only as far as:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at xx.match.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at xx.match.box.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -7
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
        at xx.match.b.a.a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried to add one of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar as suggested by the URL above but to no avail.

Does anyone know what's going on here or what I'm supposed to do next given that I don't have access to the Java-code in question? Is it a bug in the original .jar-file I'm trying to run or is there anything else I can do to make this work?

(I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer that didn't assume access to the source code... Sorry if I missed it).

Comment: Actually, SLF4J-related message is just a warning saying that it could not initialize the logging, so you will not see anything related to logs. But the actual exception is `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -7` thrown by some other code (and not slf4j-related code). Did you try to decompile the jar and look into the throwing method? http://www.javadecompilers.com/ is one of online decompilers.

Comment: Check where the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException originates from. I don't think SLF4J has any part here.

Comment: Turned out that there was a more serious bug in the original .jar file that caused this. Thanks for your suggestions, though. Much appreciated.